# CType shortcut - remove wrapping div

Tags: typo3

I tried to remove the wrapping div for the CType shortcut as follows:

```
    tt_content.shortcut.prefixComment >
    tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.override = |
    tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.override.if {
      equals = shortcut
      value.field = CType
    }
```

But it doesn't work, there's still a wrapping div around the content.

Comment: What TYPO3 version are you using? Are you using css_styled_content or fluid_styled_content? What HTML are you getting and what do you want to get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will only work when you're using css_styled_content. Starting with version 7 (or 8?) TYPO3 uses fluid_styled_content as the default. Much nicer but very different. To change the rendering of CType 'shortcut' you can now override the default fluid template for this type.

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/fluid_styled_content/Configuration/OverridingFluidTemplates/Index.html